# Can you use an AuthorizationService from an AuthorizationHandler in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm fairly new to asp.net and this is my first stackoverflow question, so please go easy on me.

I have two authorization handlers for two different resources. Access to the given resource sometimes depends on the access to the *other* resource. For the sake of good coding practice (i.e. not copying the same code to both handlers) and because the authorization logic will (perhaps often) change in the future, I'd like to just call authorization for the resource from within the handler.

Naively I just tried to inject the AuthorizationService to the handler and got an exception on startup because of a circular dependency.

```
        public class AttachmentAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<OperationAuthorizationRequirement, Attachment>
        {
            private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbcontext;
            private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;

            public AttachmentAuthorizationHandler(ApplicationDbContext dbcontext,
                                                  UserManager<User> userManager,
                                                  IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
            {
                _dbcontext = dbcontext;
                _userManager = userManager;
                _authorizationService = authorizationService;
            }

            ...    
            other authorization logic
            ...

            if(_authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(context.User, ticket, TicketOperations.Read).Result.Succeeded) 
            { 
                context.Succeed(req);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
```

```
    A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationService'.
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationService(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService) ->
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationHandlerProvider(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationHandlerProvider) ->
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationHandler> ->
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationHandler(Ticketsystem.Authorization.Attachments.AttachmentAuthorizationHandler) ->
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationService
```

Suggestions on how I can get around this?

Comment: It may help if you [edit] your question and post the details of the exception you are getting, i.e. entire error message and stack trace.

Comment: I added the error message. The problem is not the error though, I think I understand why the error is happening. I'm asking if it would be possible to use the authorization from the handler without creating circular dependencies.

Comment: It seems like a problem that your logic is mixed with the Handler implementation. Could you create a separate method or class with just the logic for the authorization? Then you can call it from the other handler without the circular reference.

Comment: Yes, that would do as a workaround for now. The problem is, the attachment handler is then strongly coupled to the other handler, because it assumes it only calls the seperate method. If this is changed, the logic breaks. 
I want the attachment handler be dependend on the ticket handler, regardless of its implementation.

Comment: Have you found any more information on this? I'm also looking for a way to call another hander within a handler.

Comment: @Canolyb1 No, not when I was still working on it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving the IAuthorizationService directly from the HttpContext.

Resolving the IAuthorizationService from the context:

```
var a = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthorizationService>();
```

and using it as:

```
var isAuthorized = await a.AuthorizeAsync(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User, Permission.RunReports);
```